# Maven Spring boot: set additional properties file location on test

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Currently, I'm setting additional spring boot properties file using `spring.config.additional-location`:

```
mvn -DskipTests spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.config.additional-location=api-props.properties
```

I'd like to know how to set this additional properties file when I test it. Up to now, I've tested to put this parameter on `test`.

```
mvn test -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.config.additional-location=api-props.properties
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are many options.
Start with application.properties in `src/test/resources` folder.

If the test is marked with `@SpringBootTest` this properties file will be picked automatically.
It will also override properties specified in "usual" application properties

Another good option is using `@TestPropertySources` annotation

For complete list see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)